# Injecting guava cache in spring

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, guava

For some reason i'm not able to construct a guava cache instance and expose it as a Spring bean.

Here is the construction code:

```
@Configuration
public class ProductRepositoryCache {

    @Bean
    public Cache<NameSearchKey,Collection<String>> nameSearchCache() {
        Cache<NameSearchKey,Collection<String>> result = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(1024)
                .expireAfterAccess(0, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .expireAfterWrite(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build();
        return  (Cache<NameSearchKey,Collection<String>>) result;
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
@Resource
Cache<NameSearchKey,Collection<String>> nameSearchCache;
```

but deployment fails with:

> Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'nameSearchCache' must be of type [com.google.common.cache.Cache], but was actually of type [com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder]|#]

I believe i'm missing something simple, but can't find it. So, my question is - what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why you need bean for this? you can use static utility method for such use case.

Comment: Why to you need to cast `result` in the last line of `nameSearchCache()`?

Comment: initially it was just a `return CacheBuilder.newBuilder....build();` then i split it to see in debugger what happens. Casting of the result was a test, whether i'm an idiot and result is actually not of a Cache type or not.

Answer (score 1):

The real return instance is `com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.LocalManualCache` which is a Cache. your code is correct I think, moreover I did the same thing before, it works fine.

I suggest to check the `BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException` which contains:

> beanName - the name of the bean requested
>
> requiredType - the required
>
> type actualType - the actual type returned, which did not match the expected type

then you could debug for the `BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException` instance to find the cause.

Also, you could declare Bean explicit name, it can avoid some error prone.

```
@Bean(name = "thisCache")
public Cache<NameSearchKey,Collection<String>> nameSearchCache() {...}

@Resource(name = "thisCache")
Cache<NameSearchKey,Collection<String>> nameSearchCache;
```